# Align top left and bottom right with material design

Tags: material-design

I might be getting this completely wrong, but trying to create a webpage where Div 1 is in top left corner, and div 2 is aligned bottom right (or end end). And I wanted to do  this in the right way using material design.
I want it like this (sorry for the ASCII art, but it is cool)

```
_____________33____50________________
|            |                       |
|    1       |                       |
|            |      _________________| 33
-------------|      |                |
|                   |        2       |
|                   |                |
|                   |                |
--------------------------------------
                    50
```

Here is the code so far, but the problem is I can get it to affect the alignment on column one, but I cant set them independently on the two divs

```
<md-content layout="column" layout-fill>
    <div layout="column" flex="33"><H1>Welcome to My page</H1>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="end end" flex="33">
        <div layout="column" layout-align="end end" flex="50">
                 <H3>Welcome to  my page</H3>
        <p>This is my page, there are many like it <bold>But this page is mine</bold></p>

        <ul>
            <li>
                My page is my best friend
            </li><li>
                I must master its code
            </li><li>
                like I must master my life
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-content>
```

Not certain the JS fiddle works at all, managed to get the first bit working, but cant get the end. Is this just because we don't know how big the screen is?

Here is a simple JS fiddle, and Material Design is working, and I can get the flex  to work, but not the align
https://jsfiddle.net/p02Ls1dh/3/

Answer (score 0):

OK, sorry, me being silly, material design still don't know the height, so the way to do it is to set height (you can use javascript and window) to set the height to say 900px (`style="height: 900px;"` below), once that is done it works.

```
<md-content layout="column" layout-fill style="height: 900px">
    <div layout="column" flex="33"><H1>Welcome to My page</H1>
    </div>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="end end" flex="33">
        <div layout="column" layout-align="end end" flex="50">
                 <H3>Welcome to  my page</H3>
        <p>This is my page, there are many like it <bold>But this page is mine</bold></p>

        <ul>
            <li>
                My page is my best friend
            </li><li>
                I must master its code
            </li><li>
                like I must master my life
            </li>
        </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</md-content>
```